# Failed to compile netperf 2.7.0 using Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I am having issue getting netperf 2.7.0 using Cygwin.  Based on what I read, many people have success getting netperf to compile using Cygwin so I am hoping that I am missing some libraries that I forgot to install and hoping someone would shed me some light on this.

Here's the sequence of steps I took  for compilation.

```
wget https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/archive/netperf-2.7.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf netperf-2.7.0.tar.gz
cd netperf-netperf-2.7.0
./configure
./make all
```

The following is a snippet of the error ouput

```
mv -f .deps/netcpu_none.Tpo .deps/netcpu_none.Po
gcc     -o netperf.exe netperf.o netlib.o netsh.o nettest_bsd.o nettest_dlpi.o nettest_unix.o nettest_xti.o nettest_sctp.o nettest_sdp.o nettest_omni.o net_uuid.o dscp.o netcpu_none.o  -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: netlib.o:netlib.c:(.text+0x1b46): undefined reference to `__CPU_ZERO'
netlib.o:netlib.c:(.text+0x1b46): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__CPU_ZERO'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: netlib.o:netlib.c:(.text+0x1b57): undefined reference to `__CPU_SET'
netlib.o:netlib.c:(.text+0x1b57): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__CPU_SET'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:305: netperf.exe] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/David Chu/workspace/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:352: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/David Chu/workspace/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:277: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/David Chu/workspace/netperf-netperf-2.7.0'
make: *** [Makefile:215: all] Error 2
```

Attached is the full compilation log

[compilation.log](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/files/4511865/compilation.log)

Thanks in advance!

Note: The same question was also posted on netperf github's project but activity on that project is low to nothing so I decided to post here as well.  https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/issues/41

Comment: That does the trick.  I was able to compile netperf successfully under Cygwin.

Comment: I put an answer just as record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make changes to /usr/include/sys/cpuset.h with #if 1 //__GNU_VISIBLE,

and remove __ from __CPU_ZERO in src/netlib.c